# FlatMap is not being called after a webclient call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have this function inside a @Service in Spring Webflux and it is called with a list of friends to know if everyone has been joined to a group. If some friends have no group this method calls an API to get its user's information and then calls another API to tag these guys with joined tag false.

```
@Service
...
  public Flux<Boolean> checkUserHaveGroup(final List<String> friends) {
    MatchOperation match1 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("friends").in(friends).and("status").is("ACTIVE"));
    UnwindOperation unwind1 = Aggregation.unwind("friends");
    MatchOperation match2 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("friends").in(friends));
    GroupOperation group1 = Aggregation.group("friends");

    TypedAggregation<Group> a = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Group.class,
        match1, unwind1, match2, group1);

    return this.reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(a, FriendInGroup.class)
        .map(friendInGroup -> friendInGroup.id)
        .collectList()
        .map(users -> haveNoGroupsList(users, friends))
        .flatMapMany(noGroupUsers -> {
          return Flux.fromIterable(noGroupUsers)
              .flatMap(pn -> crmService.deleteAttribute(pn, "joinedAGroup"));
        });
  }
```

```
(this method get the user information)
...
public Mono<UserInfo> userInfoById(final String userId) {

    return webClient.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(constants.getByIdPath() + "/{id}")
            .build(userId))
        .header("auth", tokenService.token())
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> {
          Mono<UserInfo> responseMono;

          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)) {
            responseMono = Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException());
          } else if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            responseMono = response.bodyToMono(UserInfoResponse.class)
                .flatMap(uir -> Mono.just(uir.getData()));
          } else {
            responseMono = Mono.error(new UnhandledException());
          }

          return responseMono;
        });

  }
```

```
...
  private Mono<UserInfo> getUserInfo(String userId) {
    return userInfoAdapter.userInfoById(userId);
  }


...

  public Mono<Boolean> deleteAttribute(final String userId, final String attribute) {
    return getUserInfo(userId) <<<<< here we get the users info
        .flatMap(ui -> crmDeleteAttribute(ui, attribute)); <<<< this call is never done.
  }

...


 public Mono<Boolean> crmDeleteAttribute(final UserInfo user, final String attribute) {

    return webClient.delete()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path(contants.path())
            .build(user.getId(), attribute))
        .header("auth", tokenService.token())
        .exchange().flatMap(response -> {
          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE);
          }
          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)) {
            return Mono.error(CrmServiceBadRequestException::new);
          }
          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)) {
            return Mono.error(CrmServiceUnauthorizedException::new);
          }
          return Mono.error(CrmServiceUnhandledException::new);
        });
  }
```

After getting the users' info on the API, the API for assign a tag is never been called no matter what I do. I can see in the debugger terminal that the call to UserInfo API was done but after that, the application returns to the controller. Someone could point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: is `.flatMap(uir -> Mono.just(uir.getData()));` ever called?

Comment: Yes, when the response returns it calls this flatmap to get the right data to map to UserInfo. But after that, nothing occurs.

Comment: Are you sure that getData actually returns a value. Because i suspect it doesnt.

Comment: Man! My bad. You are right. The status code was 200 but I got no results in response. Thanks!!!!!